# Guess configuration to inflate zlib compressed data

Tags: python, compression, reverse-engineering, zlib

I want to inflate a zlib compressed data. I've tried the following in python:

```
zlib.decompress(data)
```

-> it return the following error: zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check

So I found a way to ignore data check:

```py
def decompress_corrupted(data):
    d = zlib.decompressobj(zlib.MAX_WBITS | 32)
    f = BytesIO(data)
    result_str = b''
    buffer = f.read(1)
    try:
        while buffer:
            result_str += d.decompress(buffer)
            buffer = f.read(1)
    except zlib.error:
        pass
    return result_str
```

But the result produced is partially "corrupted": I get a .rtf content with few mistakes.

**My question**: since I know that the compression uses zlib algorithm, what are the configurations parts (or pre/post-processes) I could try to get the original document?

**Context**: the solution used to compress these files is no more edited and the editor has never answered our messages. We only possess a compiled viewer but need the exact algorithm to make a migration to alternative solution. We know **these files are not corrupted** since the current viewer is able to display them properly.

If it can help:

- here is the head of the data: 789C 95 54 5D 6F D3 30 14 ...
- and the tail: .. 79 AE C5 E2 17 82 5E 3F 85

Comment: Can you provide a link to the entire stream? What exactly is this "current viewer" that is your evidence that the zlib stream is not corrupted?

Comment: Sadly no, all the corrupted files we have investigated for now include sensitive data that I cannot publish. I will try to find a "neutral" document to provide a full stream.
The current viewer doesn't have a name. It's a huge binary app that has been developped by a local company to handle document archives among many other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "configurations" needed. zlib's inflate will inflate any valid compressed zlib stream losslessly to the original content.

Therefore, despite your attestation, your data is getting corrupted or deliberately modified somewhere along the way.

Comment: Wow, the zlib creator himself! That's an honor!
Thank you, I was afraid of this answer but at least it closes this part of our investigation. I guess some pre-processing is needed on the stream before inflating it...

Since the corrupted characters are not that many in the inflated documents (but can ruin the whole document when occuring in RTF tags), I guess that the alteration to the valid stream should be minor too. Am I right?
Maybe some "metadata bytes" put by the developper for whatever reason?